# Change the volume of the web speech synthesizer dynamically

Tags: web, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, avspeechsynthesizer

Issue:

As part of speech synthesis in web, i am using the webspeechsynthesizer and while playing the speech utterance i am trying to change the volume. I want the change to be reflected immediately on the speech utterance i.e while speaking.

Based on my research on the web, i don't find a way to dynamically change the volume. I tried pause and resume that does not appear to work.

Is there any possible way?

Thanks